# Replace underscores from string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a string that can contain any number of underscores many times in the string as following.

**String: "Test_test__test_test__"**

I need output like following for building SQL query.

**String: "Test[_]test[__]test[_]test[__]"**

I need to find a solution using Javascript or C#.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you share the solution you have

Comment: One should ask a question or give an answer without downvoting as nothing was wrong with my question.

Comment: not my downvote but as it stands you want someone to do your homework for you

Comment: @Maharshi yes there is. If you google [c# replace](https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=c%23+replace) you'll get your answer immediately.  This question just shows lack of effort.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method by [specifying a string as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in replace string.

```js
var str = "Test_test__test_test__";

console.log(str.replace(/_+/g, '[$&]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function

```js
var str = "Test_test__test_test__";
console.log(str.replace(/_+/g,'[$&]'));
```